# מִמֶּֽנּוּ From Us or From him/it?

Tags: grammar-dikduk

מִמֶּֽנּוּ 
On the words (siddur from Anneinu said on fast days) אַל תַּסְתֵּר פָּנֶֽיךָ מִמֶּֽנּוּ the translation on the word  מִמֶּֽנּוּ is "from us" yet isn't it supposed to mean from him/it ?  Doesn't the suffix of נּוּ vs. נוּ change the meaning from him/it to us?

Comment: No. The word can mean either one.

Comment: See Tosfot Nazir about this I don't remember the daf.I think he says that the dagesh on the nun is nafka mina but grammarians say that it's the same and always with dagesh

Comment: I agree. The ending נּוּ is used for both 2nd and 3rd person plural both Biblically as well s in modern Hebrew. You need to know the context to determine if it means "us" or "them". In some cases, it's difficult to tell.